# access violation 0040690B delphi

Tags: delphi, for-loop

My code works but keeps giving me access violation error.
" Access violation at address 00440690B in module. read of address 01F62C42."
what is wrong? and how can I make it work?
The second loop does nothing. please help!

```
Var
   num1, num2, k : Integer;
   LL : string;

begin

LL := '       ';
num1 := 4;
num2 := 4;
  for k := 1 to 7 do
    begin
      LL[num1] := '*';
      LL[num2] := '*';
      redt.Lines.Add(LL);
      num1 := num1 +1;
      num2 := num2 -1;
    end;
  for k := 1 to 3 do
redt.Lines.Add('   *   ');

end;
```

Comment: "*My code works but keeps giving me access violation error.*" - That sentence does not make any sense, logically. If your code would work, it would not throw the AV. If throwing the AV is by design, you would not ask that question. Hence, the code is **not** working, obviously.

Comment: thanks. I changed the "1 to 7" to "1 to 4" and it worked. thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My code works.

No, it does not. You are accessing elements of `LL` that are out-of-bounds. In the final iteration of the first loop, `num1` has value `10`, and `num2` has value `-2`. Both of these are out-of-bounds when used as indices for `LL`. Valid indices for `LL` are `1` to `7`. So I guess that the first loop should run for `1` to `4`.

If you would enable range checking in the compiler options, the compiler would be able to tell you this. I cannot stress enough the importance of using range checking. Use it, and let the compiler find your defects.

Comment: +1 for range checking.  And bounds checking, for that matter.  Those compiler options are there for your protection; use them unless you really really know what you're doing and you're *certain* you don't need them.

Comment: @MasonWheeler And newer versions of Delphi have multiple build configurations, so you can disable them only to release with a click... No reason to not using that options.

Comment: You can do it with older versions as well, utilizing includes and `{$IFDEF Debug}` ... `{$ELSE}`  ... `{$ENDIF}`. Not as easy as with the newer versions, but not that hard either.

Comment: @Jens You've never needed to do that. The build automation would switch that setting.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo And really, it's better not disable range checking in production code unless you have a proven performance issue in a specific section of code that would benefit...... After all, which would you prefer? **(1)** Customer complaining about an `ERangeError`, or **(2)** Customer complaining about a screwy calculation in your software that cost them thousands of dollars because you had an unexpected memory overwrite due to a range problem that was undetected.

Comment: @CraigYoung Is right. Unless performance is an issue, you may as well leave range checking on.

Comment: Agreed with David and Craig. Leave that check active until it cause something really bad in performance.